# Unable to move file from one folder to another in S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to move the file inside the S3 folder to another folder which is in the same s3 Bucket. I tried the below code

```
CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName,
                                              srcFolder+"/"+Filename, bucketName, 
                                              targetFolder+"/"+Filename);
s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
DeleteObjectRequest deleteObjRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, 
                                                        srcFolder+"/"+Filename);
s3Client.deleteObject(deleteObjRequest);
```

The folder may contain multiple file, i want to move only the selected file. Above code is not showing any error, but nothing happens. Can anyone please suggest me the right solution for it.

Comment: Can you try stopping after the copy and check the bucket?

Comment: What is the [`CopyObjectResult`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CopyObjectResult.html) returned from the `copyObject()` call?

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good initial stab just to run the following code and check what the output is, without and deletions.

Also worth checking the ACL and bucket policy on the object.

This is the format expected

`CopyObjectRequest(java.lang.String sourceBucketName, java.lang.String sourceKey, java.lang.String destinationBucketName, java.lang.String destinationKey)`

If you want a copy of the object in the same bucket

`CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest("myBucket", "myObject.txt", "myBucket", "myNewObject.txt");

s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);`

If you want a copy of the object in a different bucket

`CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest("myBucket", "myObject.txt", "myOtherBucket", "myNewObject.txt");

s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);`

Sample code for testing

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest;

public class CopyObjectSingleOperation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String clientRegion = "*** Client region ***";
        String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
        String sourceKey = "*** Source object key *** ";
        String destinationKey = "*** Destination object key ***";

        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .build();

            // Copy the object into a new object in the same bucket.
            CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName, sourceKey, bucketName, destinationKey);
            s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
        }
        catch(AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client  
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do I mention my source and target folder names

Comment: @kaviya.P  here is the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CopyObjectRequest.html which might make things clear.

Comment: The "sourceKey" is the key of the existing object, and the "destinationKey" is the keyName you want to use for the copy of the source object
`CopyObjectRequest(java.lang.String sourceBucketName, java.lang.String sourceKey, java.lang.String destinationBucketName, java.lang.String destinationKey)`